# How to select a single Entity by key (low level java datastore API)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm a bit confused on how to create a "Key" object to select exactly 1 row of my Entity ("Customer").

My code :

```
Query query = new Query("Customer");
// **** how do I have to create this key ???
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("Customer", 1);
// ****
FilterPredicate keyFilter =  new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,       FilterOperator.EQUAL, key);
query.setFilter(keyFilter);
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
Entity customer = pq.asSingleEntity();
if  (! (customer == null)) {
    log.info("OK !");
}
else {
    log.info("no customer found");
}
```

My result is always : "no customer found".

With the datastore viewer (I'm working locally) I can see 3 rows :

- id/name = 1   email = "your email" name = "your name"
- id/name = 2   email = "your email" name = "your name"
- id/name = 3   email = "your email" name = "your name"

I want to select customer with id/name=1.
I've tried :
KeyFactory.createKey("Customer", 1);
and
KeyFactory.createKey("Customer", "your name");

but with no success.

When I do programmatically a search (asList) on "Customer" and I print the keys' values I see :

- row 1 key = Customer("your name")/Customer(1)
- row 2 key = Customer("your name")/Customer(2)
- row 3 key = Customer("your name")/Customer(3)

The printable values of the keys are in the format : "Entity(name)/Entity(id/name)"

How can I create such key values in my code ?
On the javadoc I see only :

- createKey("kind", id)
- createKey("kind", "name")

The other methods require an ancestor, I've not created an ancestor .... 
This is the code that I've executed to created the 3 rows (it has been executed 3 times) :

```
Key customerKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Customer", "your name");
Entity customer = new Entity("Customer", customerKey);
customer.setProperty("name", "your name");
customer.setProperty("email", "your email");
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
datastore.put(customer);
```

Thanks in advance !

Regards

Max

**In other words, how do create a Key whose "toString" gives the following result ?**

- Code : log.info("customer KeyFactory.keyToString =  "+KeyFactory.keyToString(key));
- Output : INFO: customer KeyFactory.keyToString = Customer("your name")/Customer(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of the Entities is not correct.
You dont have to create a key on your own. 
If you create a Entity with a kind and keyname or ID parameter, a key will be created automaticlly out of the kind and the keyname or ID.

```
Entity customer = new Entity("Customer", "your name");
customer.setProperty("email", "your email");

DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
datastore.put(customer);
```

That is all you need to create the Entity you want.

When you give a kind and a key, a child Entity will be created.
So you had created a Customer with "your name" who is a Customer with the ID 1.

To get the Entity with a key you just have to take the same parameters to create a key.

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("Customer", "your name");
```

I would prefer to use get(), but i dont know what you want to do.
For Example to get the email of a Customer:

```
    Entity e;
    try {
        e = datastore.get(key);

        String myEmail= (String) e.getProperty("your email");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use get() not query() when you have a Key.

[https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#get(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#get%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key%29)

Comment: That's my problem. I do not know how to create the key.

Comment: Normally, I just let the datastore make my keys for me. However, if you need to assign explicit IDs to entities, here is how I did it: first use KeyFactory.createKey with entity name and ID, then create an Entity passing the Key class to the constructor, then use setProperties to assign the value to the entity created, then call DatastoreService.put passing the entity as the parameter.

Comment: You can use arbitrary strings for createKey(kind, name). For instance, I made a key ("sphere","Test Title2/601") and then created the entity and set the Title to "Test Title2" and put it. The key string of the entity is "sphere(\"Test Title2/601\")".

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you have a Java entity class called `Product` and you wish to retrieve a unique record given its key i.e. ID

The method would look something like this:

```
    public Product getProduct(Long id) {

        //Get Persistence Manager
        PersistenceManager pm = ...;

        Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(Product.class.getSimpleName(), id);
        Product product = null;
        try {
           product = pm.getObjectById(Product.class, k);
        } 
        finally {
           pm.close();
        }

    return product;
}
```

So in your example, I think you can replace `Product` with your class name. I guess your class name is `Customer`

Comment: I do not have a Java entity class "Customer", I'm using low level java api (I think u map entities to java classes only with jpa and jdo)